# How to add multiple reviewers at once using restApi

Tags: api, rest, gerrit

With below Rest-api i could able to add single reviewer into a change.

```
POST /changes/myProject~master~I8473b95934b5732ac55d26311a706c9c2bde9940/reviewers HTTP/1.0
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

  {
    "reviewer": "john.doe@example.com"
  }
```

Further how to add multiple reviewers at once using `RestApi`for a change in gerrit?

Answer (score 0):

Simply add more reviewer lines, like in the following example:

```
curl --silent --user USER:PASSWORD --request POST  --data @- --header Content-Type:application/json https://GERRIT-SERVER/a/changes/CHANGE-NUMBER/reviewers << EOF
{
    "reviewer": "john.doe",
    "reviewer": "jane.doe",
    "reviewer": "john.doe.brother"
}
EOF
```

Comment: I'm using this command `curl -k -u USERID:HTTP_PASSWORD -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"reviewer": "User1@company.com","reviewer": "User2@company.com"}' https://Gerrit-server.com/gerrit/a/changes/I2b4r5b047d04bda2304d742afe6cff6ce64a570r/reviewers` Still it adds single reviewer. Skipping other reviewer ID. Any additional option am i missing here?

Comment: Things to check: 1) why there is an extra "gerrit" word between "Gerrit-server.com" and "a" in the URL? 2) the additional users really exist in Gerrit (the users must log in to Gerrit first to be added as reviewer) 3) try to use the same command I used in the example.

Comment: `https://Gerrit-server.com/gerrit/` is our base url and users are already existing in gerrit and they have repository access permission. Even the above command also adds single reviewer and skips remaining.